# Not sure why my click event won't work?

Tags: jquery, css, click

I've set up a click event to change the background color of the entire page to green upon the user button being clicked, but when I click it nothing happens. I'm extremely new to jQuery, so I'm sure I'm making an obvious error.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $body = $('body')
    /*$body.html('');*/

    //  var currentView = "Twittler Feed"
    var currentView = $('<p>Twittler Feed</p>');
    var refreshTweet = function() {
        var index = streams.home.length - 1;
        var endInd = index - 10;
        while (index >= endInd) {
            var tweet = streams.home[index];
            var $tweet = $('<div class="tweets"><p class="posted-by"><button class="user">@' +
                tweet.user + '</button><p class="message">' + tweet.message +
                '</p><p class="time">' + /*$.timeago(tweet.created_at)*/ tweet.created_at + '</p></div>');
            currentView.appendTo('#sidebar')
            $tweet.appendTo($body);
            index -= 1;
        }
    }

    refreshTweet();

    $('.refresh').on('click', function() {
        if (document.getElementsByClassName('tweets')) {
            $('.tweets').remove();
        }
        var result = refreshTweet();
        $body.prepend(result);
    })

    $('.user').on('click', 'button', function() {
        currentView = this.user
        $('body').css('background-color', 'green');

    });
});
```

Comment: change `$('document').css('background-color', 'green');` to `$('body').css('background-color', 'green');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ever you are defining or registering an event using ID or CLASS you have to use the corresponding operators # and .

Since user is a class use .user for registering click event

```
  $(document).on('click', '.user', function() {
    currentView = this.user;
    $('body').css('background-color', 'green');

   });
```

Reference for on() jquery http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thanks for the updates! I made the suggested changes, but the button still isn't working, unfortunately.

Comment: @RyanAttick try the update dcode now .. Also see if you see any errors on the console.

Answer (score 0):

If you want assign a click event to the class "user", you should use `.user` (and not user without dot).

```
  $('.user').on('click', 'button', function() {
    currentView = this.user
    $('body').css('background-color', 'green');

   });
```